# Raspberry pi Ibeacon does not search for IOS devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I have just turned my raspberry PI into ibeacon following instructions online.
It searches for all the devices but not IOS and even if it does it shows a weak signal
Any reason or solution for this?
When I try `hcitool scan`
It shows my Iphone but when I try this:

```
l2ping -c 1 18:34:5A:17:49:7A
```

It shows error and displays Raspberry-pi-0 not in range
So I do not understand why is it not detecting my Iphone when it is less 1 m away

Comment: Can you post more detail for your question?  Perhaps describe the devices you are detecting correctly.  For iOS devices where you are having trouble, describe how often you see their advertisements vs. how often you would expect to.  (Please paste a copy of the detection output.)  Also, please describe how you know "it shows a weak signal".  Thanks!

Comment: Also, to be clear, are you using your Raspberry Pi to *transmit* as an iBeacon, or to *scan* for iBeacons?  Your question sounds like you are trying to scan, but the first sentence says "I have just turned my raspberry Pi into ibeacon" which implies you are transmitting.

Comment: It's possible that even when nominally acting as a beacon, it can still see (perhaps classic bluetooth) devices which are set to be discoverable.  Generally one would not want a mobile phone set that way, but perhaps the poster's non-iOS devices are.  This would have essentially nothing to do with beacon capability, so the question probably arrises from misunderstanding.

Comment: But the iphone is set to be discoverable and it is discovered but loses connection, it says it is not possible to pair it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I don't think the iPhones will pair with arbitrary devices on classic blueooth, and at any rate this would have little to do with most practical "beacon" schemes.